# Deploying express app into firebase from different module is not working

Tags: node.js, firebase, deployment, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy my express app to cloud Firebase.
If I use the following code inside functions\index.js everything works fine:

**index.js**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.get("/log1", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello world");
});
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I tried to move the app to external file which will look like this:

**serv.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/log", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Helldddo world");
});

// exports.app = app;
module.exports ={
  app:app
}
```

Then the index.js will look like this:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const server = require("./serv");
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(server.app);
```

This work fine . 
But If I change **serv.js** location to upper folder and change the import to

```
const server = require("../serv");
```

I get an error:

```
!  functions[app(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '../myserv'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/index.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)


Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        app


To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only functions:app


To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase CLI will only package and deploy the files in your functions folder.  If you try to reference a file that doesn't live within that space, it won't be found at runtime.  So, before you deploy, make sure you are only using files that physically exist in the functions folder.